# Having troble to read a var using FOREACH in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am having trouble with the following pig code.

The previus var I need to read via FOREACH has the following DESCRIBE:

> UnionD1D2_Distinct: {UnionD1D2_Foreach1::null::display_site:
> chararray,UnionD1D2_Foreach1::efectivos_click:
> long,UnionD1D2_Foreach2::null::display_site:
> chararray,UnionD1D2_Foreach2::total_click: long}

And here, example data:

> (linuxlife.example.com,113,linuxlife.example.com,5343)
> (mobilesource.example.com,211,mobilesource.example.com,8120)
> (siliconshore.example.com,170,siliconshore.example.com,7764)
> (printoperator.example.com,62,printoperator.example.com,2724)

So, the FOREACH reads the data is:

```
UnionD1D2_Calc = FOREACH UnionD1D2_Distinct
  GENERATE
    (UnionD1D2_Distinct.UnionD1D2_Foreach1::efectivos_click1/UnionD1D2_Distinct.UnionD1D2_Foreach2::total_click2)*100 AS ctr;
```

But, I'm always getting the following:

> ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias UnionD1D2_Calc. Backend
> error : Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st :
> (filmport.example.com,121,filmport.example.com,5395), 2nd
> :(firesale.example.com,129,firesale.example.com,5452)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `FOREACH` on an alias, you don't need to use the alias name again to refer to a variable. For example, instead of `UnionD1D2_Distinct.UnionD1D2_Foreach1::efectivos_click1` you can just use `UnionD1D2_Foreach1::efectivos_click1`.

Please try:

```
UnionD1D2_Calc = FOREACH UnionD1D2_Distinct GENERATE
    (UnionD1D2_Foreach1::efectivos_click1/UnionD1D2_Foreach2::total_click2)*100 AS ctr;
```

And let us know if you get the same error.